# Programmaticaly add centralized SSL certificate store with APPCMD

Tags: php, iis, ssl-certificate, appcmd

I am creating a webinterface in `PHP` for basic updates to websites in IIS. One part is to add a new website and add the correct binding. I use the following commands to add a binding:

```
appcmd add site /name:"sitename" /bindings:"http://example.com:80" /physicalPath:"d:\websites"
appcmd set site /site.name:"sitename" /+bindings.[protocol='https',sslflags='3',bindingInformation='*:443:example.com']
```

I use the SSL Flag 3 to use the centralized SSL certificate store as specified in the [Microsoft Binding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)

Everything seems to work fine as the site is added with both bindings and HTTP works. When I use HTTPS however, it keeps giving a connection reset error.

The only way to fix this is to open the bindings in `IIS Manager`, change something in *any* SSL binding without saving and change it back, just to make the "Ok" button available and press it. (EG: Port to 442 and back to 443) Nothing has changed in the actual settings and there are no changes to `applicationHost.config`.

After doing this, it all works.

What I tried without succes:

1. iisreset command, no change
2. start/stop/restart website
3. start/stop/restart server
4. reboot server
5. tried several different servers

What could the `binding dialog` be doing that fixes this weird problem?

Comment: Here is a reference may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-centralized-ssl-certificate-support-ssl-scalability-and-manageability

Comment: Thank you. Buried in there was the solution. When running `netsh http show sslcert` I didn't get anything back so I needed to add the CCS with `netsh`. The command listed was plain wrong, but it did help find the correct one: `netsh http add sslcert appid={GUID} ccs=443`